# Updating old code, but it now has forward declaration errors

Tags: java, server, base64, minecraft, decoder

I'm not very proficient in Java, I'm just getting started. However, the need arose to update someone else's work for my own uses (privately, of course). Once I got started updating the Plugin (this is specifically for a Spigot Minecraft server), I ran into a ton of sloppy code and many, many errors. This one has stumped me as a newbie to the Java scene.

The code is for a Base64 decoder.

```
private static final char[] map1 = new char[64];

static { int i = 0;
    for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c = (char)(c + '\001')) map1[(i++)] = c;
    for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c = (char)(c + '\001')) map1[(i++)] = c;
    for (char c = '0'; c <= '9'; c = (char)(c + '\001')) map1[(i++)] = c;
    map1[(i++)] = '+';map1[(i++)] = '/';

    map2 = new byte['<nonunicodechar>']; // It appears as a square in IntelliJ, assuming it's not unicode (see below)

    for (int i = 0; i < map2.length; i++) map2[i] = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) { map2[map1[i]] = ((byte)i);
  }
}

public static final byte[] map2;
```

The issues thrown are that map2 is an illegal forward reference, and that 'i' is already defined in scope.

What the `byte[''];` looks as follows

[image: Code]

Comment: Not exactly your Q but: (1) `c++` or `c+=1` handles the cast back to `char` for you (2) the box glyph is usually displayed as a substitute for any undisplayable Java-char and so _could_ be many things, but I'd bet it's _probably_ `(char)127` aka `\u007F`; depending on the editor(s) you use you might be able to get the underlying code, or on a Unixy system use `od` or `xxd` or similar on the file (3) if Spigot uses Oracle Java, the current version (8) has [`java.util.Base64` click doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) in the standard library which may be easier

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Yeah, I did notice that it's included now, and the only reason I'm using this code is because another class relies on this base64 decoder. I'm not sure how I would implement the integrated version (again, extremely basic knowledge here) either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, a static constructor like this will just insert itself into the order of normal class initialisation. So in your case, map1 is declared, then the static code block is run, then map is declared.

Try moving the declaration of map2 above the static code block.

Comment: Tried doing this, moved it under `private static final char[] map1 = char[64];`, but now it throws the unknown class error for map2. I assume I moved it to the wrong spot?

Comment: No that's the right spot... and it sounds like it solved your initial problem and exposed another... Could you post the details of the unknown class error?

Also, I just noticed the problem with "i". You have it declared at the top of the static block but then you try to declare it again later in your for loops... try changing your for loop variables to "j" or something more descriptive.

Comment: Sorry this took so for the reply. Actually when I edited it on a Unixy system, the line is `map2 = new byte[''];`. That also throws an error, "Empty Character Literal". When I change it to i to something else, it says that the new "i" is never used.

Comment: Oh, it looks like its trying to declare an array with a character for its size. I haven't seen that done before. Try changing your unicode character to Character.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: So, changed it to `map2 = new byte["Character.MAX_VALUE."];` but it throws the error that it expects an integer but gets a string now

Comment: Take away the quotes and the "." at the end. i.e. `map2 = new byte[Character.MAX_VALUE];`

Comment: Okay, that fixed it, and now moving `public static final byte[] map2;` doesn't break it, and now the issue with 'i' not being anywhere else is fixed too. Now, onto fixing the rest of this code (in a different question thread). Thanks so much for your help @Maybe_Factor